# OnClick Adapter on Kotlin

Tags: debugging, kotlin

My kotlin code brakes when the onclick adapterPosition. I've debug the code but I'm still not sure what is going on and why is not working.

Here is my Category Adapter:

```
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import com.google.android.gms.common.internal.service.Common
import com.letsbuildthatapp.kotlinmessenger.Quizz.Model.Category
import com.letsbuildthatapp.kotlinmessenger.Quizz.Model.Interface.IOnRecyclerViewItemClickListener
import com.letsbuildthatapp.kotlinmessenger.Quizz.Model.Question

import com.letsbuildthatapp.kotlinmessenger.R



class CategoryAdapter(internal var context: Context,
                      internal var categoryList: List<Category>):

RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {
    //This is correct
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, p1: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_category_item, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    // this is correct
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return categoryList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.txt_category_name.text = categoryList[position].name
        holder.setiOnRecyclerViewItemClickListener(object : IOnRecyclerViewItemClickListener {
            override fun onClick(view: View?, position: Int) {
                // this is to direct user to the question List
                com.letsbuildthatapp.kotlinmessenger.Quizz.Model.Common.Common.selectedCategory = categoryList[position]
                val intent = Intent(context, Question::class.java)
                context.startActivity(intent)
            }

        })

    }

    inner class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView), View.OnClickListener {

        internal var txt_category_name: TextView
        internal var card_category: CardView
        internal lateinit var iOnRecyclerViewItemClickListener: IOnRecyclerViewItemClickListener


        fun setiOnRecyclerViewItemClickListener(iOnRecyclerViewItemClickListener: IOnRecyclerViewItemClickListener) {
            this.iOnRecyclerViewItemClickListener = iOnRecyclerViewItemClickListener
        }


        init {
            txt_category_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_category_name) as TextView
            card_category = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_category) as CardView

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
        }


        override fun onClick(view: View?) {
            iOnRecyclerViewItemClickListener.onClick(view, adapterPosition)

        }
    }
}
```

Here is the IonRecyclerViewItemClickLister

```
interface IOnRecyclerViewItemClickListener {

    fun onClick(view: View?, position:Int)
}
```

I've debugged the code and it appears to work well until it reaches to this part:

```
        override fun onClick(view: View?) {
            iOnRecyclerViewItemClickListener.onClick(view, adapterPosition)

        }
    }
}
```

My question is what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Can you post exception stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

Implement your interface in your activity and pass it as parameter to your Adapter. After pass it your view holder.

I'll let you with an example of my project.

[My interface](https://github.com/Kugra/MyNotes/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/kovalsikoski/johan/mynotes/NoteInterface.kt)

[MainActivity - Where I implement the Interface](https://github.com/Kugra/MyNotes/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/kovalsikoski/johan/mynotes/MainActivity.kt)

[My adapter](https://github.com/Kugra/MyNotes/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/kovalsikoski/johan/mynotes/MyNotesAdapter.kt)

Answer (score 0):

I discovered where the error was

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.txt_category_name.text = categoryList[position].name
    holder.setiOnRecyclerViewItemClickListener(object : IOnRecyclerViewItemClickListener {
        override fun onClick(view: View?, position: Int) {
            // this is to direct user to the question List
            com.letsbuildthatapp.kotlinmessenger.Quizz.Model.Common.Common.selectedCategory = categoryList[position]
            val intent = Intent(context, Question::class.java)
            context.startActivity(intent)
        }

    })

}
```

The error was in point to an Activity that doesn't exist.